# Fragment within fragment data transfer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, maps

I have a fragment which has 2 fragments in it. There are next and back button in outer fragment and by those buttons I change fragments. It is like

[This is what it seems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR6Ip.png)

I want to transfer data between those fragments and could not achieve it, yet. It is not obvious for me to transfer data from inner fragment to outer one. Also, I have maps in one of those fragments and map works async.

Comment: The idea is pass data from first inner fragment to outer fragment, then in outer fragment you forward the data to second inner fragment.

Comment: how can I pass from inner to outer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a reference to parent/outer fragment you should use [getParentFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#getparentfragment) API.

**Step 1:** In first inner fragment, declare a new interface to pass data from this fragment to outer fragment.

```
public class Inner1Fragment extends Fragment {

    // Call this method when you want to pass data to outer fragment (such as users press on a button on this fragment)
    private void onButtonClick() {
        // Pass the message to OuterFragment.
        OnMessageListener listener = (OnMessageListener) getParentFragment();
        listener.onMessage("Message from Inner1Fragment");
    }

    // Declare an interface to pass data to outer fragment.
    public interface OnMessageListener {
        void onMessage(String message);
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Let outer fragment implements the `OnMessageListener` and write code to forward the message to second inner fragment.

```
public class OuterFragment extends Fragment implements Inner1Fragment.OnMessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        // Forward the message to Inner2Fragment
        Inner2Fragment fragment = (Inner2Fragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Inner2Fragment");
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.onReceiveMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** In the second inner fragment write code to process the received message (I show the message by using Toast API).

```
public class Inner2Fragment extends Fragment {

    public void onReceiveMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: OnMessageListener listener = (OnMessageListener) getParentFragment(); in this part getParentFragment() returns null. In my outer fragment I use  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction() to change fragment and cannot use getChildFragmentManager.beginTransaction() as it crashes app.

Comment: Why `getChildFragmentManager` crash your app, what is error?

Comment: oh I handled it and now it works like charm. Thank you so much. This message thing will help me in other issues, too. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Happy coding :)